# Как в c# преобразовать 12-значное десятичное целое число без знака в byte[5] 5 байт информации?

Tags: c#, byte

В C# есть специальная функция для этого?
например

```
    long x = 447002003434
```

Превратить в

```
    byte[5] arr
```

Чтоб я его мог в файл записать

Comment: С плавающей точкой или целое? Со знаком или без?

Comment: без знака, целое

Comment: Преобразовать в стандартное бинарное (машинное) 8-байтное представление и откусить лишние начальные нулевые биты.

Comment: уточнил, чтоб получилось ровно 5 байт. 12-значное целое десятичное число без знака 5 байт как раз и занимает

Comment: а `BitConverter.GetBytes (Int32/64)` - пробовали?

Comment: Я ж говорю - превращайте в обычное Int64. Старшие 3 байта будут нулевые - фтопку их, а остаток в массив.

Comment: соответственно вашему примеру: `var someArr=BitConverter.GetBytes (x);` дальше проверка на длину, если больше, решайте сами какие вам байты нужны, если меньше, то решайте какие байты запишите!

Answer (score 3):

Гулять, так гулять. Предложу еще один способ.

Используем `union`. Благодаря этому никаких вычислений делать не нужно. Помещаем в поле `Long` наше значение, в поле `Array` автоматически мапятся байты.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe struct Wrapper
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long Long;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte Array[5];
}
```

Использование:

```
Wrapper wrapper;
wrapper.Long = 447002003434;

unsafe
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Console.Write(wrapper.Array[i] + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

В свойствах проекта должен быть разрешен небезопасный код.

Comment: Очень красивое решение)

Comment: Ну, на самом деле это решение не очень красивое именно из-за использования unsafe. Поле `Array` на первый взгляд является обычным массивом, но реально это указатель типа `byte*`. Поэтому с ним нельзя использовать `foreach` и LINQ.

Comment: Оно, конечно, понятно. Да и индексаторы, кстати, к `fixed`-структурам нельзя было напрямую использовать до `C# 7.3` (необходимо было использовать конструкцию `fixed (byte* x = Array) { ... }` (если мне память не изменяет). Красивыми я называю любые не самые очевидные решения)

Answer (score 2):

Если не хотите заморачиваться с длиной байт массива, вот не самое эффективное, но работающее решение для беззнакового целого

```
byte[] To(ulong inp)
{
    var res = new byte[5];
    for (var i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
        res[i] = (byte)inp;
        inp >>= 8;
    }
    return res;
}

ulong From(byte[] data)
{
    ulong res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <5 ; i++)
    {
        res += (ulong)(data[i]) << i*8;     
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long x = 447002003434;
byte[] arr = new byte[5];
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0, arr, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Я не уверен на 100%, но разве не с 0 элемента надо копировать из исходного массива? `Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0, arr, 0, 5);`

Comment: @tym32167, Точно